# Background color of a textfield in a form

Tags: forms, textfield

I'm using MikTex and Texmaker to create forms filled by clients. I just want to change the background color of the textfield, how to do it ?

```
\TextField[bordercolor=, backgroundcolor={red}, strokecolor={black},width=6.5cm,name=MyTextField]{}.
```

I'm new to Latex and searched many posts, couldn't find the right answer.

What are the name of the properties we can set for a textfield (like width=xxcm, bordercolor=none), could you take me in a right direction please ?

I would ike the backgorund color of my textfield in PDF either transparent or white.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{Form}
        \TextField[name=Text, width=\linewidth, bordercolor={black}]{}
    \end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image: TextField before entering anything]

TextField before entering anything

[image: TextField after entering something and leaving the field]

TextField after entering something and leaving the field

With `$backgroundcolor={white}$` the background color of the field becomes white while the curor is in the field but when clicking somewhere else the color changes back.

Comment: You can use `backgroundcolor={}` to set the background to transparent.

Answer (score 1):

The most important part is that you need a Form environment. With it it should work (but there is no strokecolor option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
\begin{Form}
\TextField[bordercolor=green, backgroundcolor={red},width=6.5cm,name=MyTextField]{}.
\end{Form}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't resolve the problem:(

Comment: This answer doesn't address the question.

Answer (score -1):

Including a minimum working example (MWE) that shows the packages you're working with is always helpful.  I assume you're working with the hyperref package based on the `\TextField` environment.

### Finding LaTeX documentation

To quickly access documentation you can use the `texdoc` command to access the documdentation for various LaTeX packages (`texdoc hyperref`) or you can simply google your package name along with CTAN (e.g. `hyperref ctan`) to quickly find the corresponding package info (usually including docs) on the "CTAN Comprehensive TeX Archive Network"

### What the hyperref docs say

pp. 36-37 of the hyperref PDF docs list all the parameters you can set for forms environments like `\TextField`.

Comment: This answer does not address the main question.

Comment: Teach a man to fish...